# How to update a column in a table at a given time?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a schedule table that has these columns:

```
job_id(varchar2), start_time(date), end_time(date), active(varchar2)
```

I want a procedure that takes in these parameters:

```
Procedure set_time(job_id in, mode in, start_or_end_time in)
```

if the user calls the procedure with these values:

```
set_time('job1','start','a date 02/06/18 for example')
```

I would like the table **schedule** to be updated and the active column set to 'Y'
for that job_id at that specific date/time. So the active column should be set to 'Y' only when that date/time is reached.

or

If the procedure is called with these values:

```
set_time('job1','end','a date 02/07/18')
```

I want the record for job1 to be updated on 02/07/18 and the active column set to 'N' only when the date given is reached.

My question is how can I update a record to be active ('Y') at a certain date/time and then to deactivate ('N') it at a specific date/time? So basically a user can set an interval on when job_id can be active.

Example: I want job_id X to be active (set to 'Y') only from 02/06/18 to 02/09/18.

Comment: that's a *bad* idea: just save your dates and use `current_timestamp` in a query or a view  to calculate the `active` column whenever you need it (eg: `case when current_timestamp between table.start and table.end then 'Y' else 'N' end`)

Comment: it's bad for a number of reasons: think eg what happens if the db server is down when your job needs to run or if, after your job runs, a previous backup is restored... anyway, Oracle has builtin jobs if you really need them - see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedover004.htm#ADMIN12359

Comment: Thanks for the feedback i will play around with adding both dates and using current_time stamp in my procedure to determine the active column. I thought about using a job but I didnt want to have a job running all day checking for changes.

Comment: Database job won't be *running* all day, it'll run at the specific time of a day. If it is about *checking for changes*, then it doesn't sound like a scheduled job, but a *database trigger*.